# Swift animate UIView with multiple options

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, xcode6, uiviewanimation

How does swift handle multiple options when animating UIView? I tried

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse, animations: {self.alpha = 0.0}, completion: nil)
```

but seems to confuse the `|` with a bitwise operator:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "__TFSsoi1oUSs17_RawOptionSetType_USs21BitwiseOperationsTypeSs9Equatable__FTQ_Q__Q_", referenced from:
      __TFC17TextDrawing10cursorViewW8blinkingSb in cursorView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using the latest Xcode version from the AppStore.

Comment: Seems that there is no problems with code. Have you tried deleted derived data for the project and cleaning the build?

Comment: I cleaned the build (Product -> Clean) and deleted the derived data. It still gives the very same error.

Comment: Try a clean build folder too: Project -> (hold down Alt key) -> Clean Build Folder

Comment: Could you just double-check the exact build version number of Xcode you've got there for us, please? (Xcode menu/About Xcode) And can you reproduce the problem in a new, minimal project? (I agree with the others: I'm using | to combine UIViewAnimationOptions values just fine...) I'm wondering if there's something else in the code/build settings that's confusing the compiler/linker...

Comment: Also, it looks like you're building for the simulator (i.e. i386)—do you get the same problem building for a real device?

Comment: Put the class into another project, compiles just fine. The project where it belongs was created in the early xcode6 beta versions. I'll see what's different w/ the build settings

Comment: @MattGibson - It doesn't build for a device either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Swift 2**:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 0.0}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 0.0}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

The preview answer won't work in nowdays swift. The good answer was given by @mxcl.

If despite all you want to use this form, you have to retrieve the rawValue and rebuild a new UIViewAnimationOptions with an inclusive OR mask.

```
UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue:(UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse.rawvalue | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat.rawValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:
Tested and ok:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) it looks like what you are doing is correct?

Have you tried wrapping the options in parentheses?

Either that or put the options into a variable first and try that?

Comment: I tried both, and it gives the same error when compiling.

Comment: @Hristo Have you tried referencing them fully? i.e. put `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` etc...

Answer (score -1):

This is working code for me:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
            disc.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            }) { (success) -> Void in
        }
```